# Multiple average chances or one better then average chance?

Tags: probability

is 52 chances at 30/5,489,031,744 odds better then 1 chance at 1560/5,489,031,744 odds

or is it the same?

Comment: They are the same, assuming these are completely independent events (30*52=1560).

Comment: Better in what sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are almost the same, but I don't think they're quite exactly the same.

But we can check it using the binomial distribution. Let p denote the probability of success in 1 average chance.

Then $\mathbb{P}$(at least 1 success)$ = 1 - \mathbb{P}$(no successes)$ = 1 - (1-p)^{52}$.

The alternative is $52p$ for the higher chance probability.

Bernoulli's inequality says for $x \geq -1, (1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$.

So we know that $1-(1-p)^{52} \geq 1-(1-52p) = 52p$

SO the probability obtained from lots of smaller chances is almost the same as one larger chance (due to $p$ being so small), but there is a very very small difference between them.